# A way to conditionally log Hibernate's SQL generation?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, logging

It seems that you can only log **all** of the SQL generated by Hibernate which makes it rather confusing if you have lots of things going on and you only want to watch something specific.

My grand aspiration is to have logging only on SQL that takes a certain amount of time to execute or even better is some annotation driven AspectJ magic such that if a method is annotated similar to Spring's `@Transaction` all of the SQL used in that transaction/method would be dumped.

I know there are some JDBC wrappers but all of them seem rather old and clunky not to mention they are devoid of any entity/programmatic information (like what Hibernate entity although I supposed you could parse the SQL and look for the tables).

Has anyone had success with conditional logging of Hibernate?

Comment: I can think of a solution. If you are using Log4j or Logback, define a custom Appender, and do the magic you want. Just define an aspect to set/unset a flag in a ThreadLocal variable, and check that variable in the Appender. By the way, I'm not sure but I believe Logback sends logging to appenders asynchronously, if that's the case, you shall think of InheritableThreadLocals (I don't know whether log4j does the same or not).

Comment: Ah yes that makes sense. Instead of a custom appender I might be able to do it with log4j/logback MDC stuff.